# PHP: Get argument count

Tags: php, function, count, arguments

This was incredibly surprising to see that PHP has no *obvious* function to do what I'm looking for, so I'll ask here.

How would you go about getting the number of arguments a particular function has *outside* of the function (just like `func_num_args` only from *outside* the function).

The solution can't actually execute the function (that would be defeating the purpose), and I'd like to do it (preferably) without any sort of reflection class.

Possible?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Oh, you can use the [`ReflectionFunction`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.reflectionfunction.php) class, which inherits from [`ReflectionFunctionAbstract`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.reflectionfunctionabstract.php), which defines the `getNumberOfParameters` function:

```
$func_reflection = new ReflectionFunction('function_name');
$num_of_params = $func_reflection->getNumberOfParameters();
```

**Note:** This will only work on user functions, not class or instance functions.

Comment: So now my concern is cost: is using the reflection class expensive?

Comment: @Di-0xide, I think it is, but what choice do you have?

Comment: @Jacob Relkin, true... I may do a manual alternative for my solution instead of trying to do it dynamically. For the sake of the question your answer is a valid solution. Thanks for the help!

Comment: You can do it on class methods just as easily - http://www.php.net/manual/en/reflectionclass.getmethod.php

Comment: @CaseySoftware True, my point is that `ReflectionFunction` only works on user functions.

Comment: @CaseySoftware, very true. However, Reflection classes are (as my research shows) at least 500% slower than calls like `get_class_methods`, so I was trying to avoid them altogether! :]

Comment: it also work on closures that don't have name like those in php variables.