# How to count the arguments of a method before calling that method which is inside a class?

Tags: php

My question is pretty much like this one: [PHP: Get argument count](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4580619/php-get-argument-count)

Except that I need to count the parameters (arguments if you prefer) of a method, but this method is inside a object.

I tried this:

```
    $reflection = new ReflectionFunction($_SITE,$acao);
    $qtdArgumentos = $reflection->getNumberOfParameters();
```

and this :

```
    $reflection = new ReflectionFunction($_SITE->$acao);
    $qtdArgumentos = $reflection->getNumberOfParameters();
```

and got this error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'ReflectionException' with message 'Function $_SITE,$acao() does not exist' in C:\wamp\www\project\index.php:20
> Stack trace:
> #0 C:\wamp\www\project\index.php(20): ReflectionFunction->__construct('$_SITE,$acao')
> #1 {main} thrown in C:\wamp\www\projeto\index.php on line 20

Does anyone knows another way to count the number of arguments of a method is inside a object or a workaround for my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you need is [ReflectionMethod](http://php.net/manual/en/reflectionmethod.construct.php)

```
 $reflection = new ReflectionMethod($_SITE, $acao);
 $qtdArgumentos = $reflection->getNumberOfParameters();
```

Comment: As you can see I tried that already and it gave me the same error. Thank you for replying.